# Jupyter Notebook R Kernel Max_Rows Option?

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-irkernel

I have a table of coefficeints (other stat output) that is being abridged.

Is there an option (or hack) in an R-Kernel Jupyter Notebook to output a full data.table? Similar to the Pandas option `pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)` you can use in the regular python Jupyter Notebook.

Is this on the R side or on the Jupyter side?

Comment: If you don't care about the jupyter notebook table display, try print(dt,nrow=500)

Comment: This has much less to do with `jupyter` than it has to do with `R` and the `data.table` package. Try setting the max number of rows to be printed with `options(datatable.print.nrows = 500)` after you have imported the library.

Comment: @Abdou I don't think that will run in jupyter, `jupyter` does seem to have its own table trimming going on. For instance running `data.frame(iris)` in jupyter will still hide a lot of the rows.

Comment: @Chris - Just using print does work after i set ```options(width = 2000)```- initially it was pushing columns to another level. This does seem to be a Jupyter issues,  I would prefer to have a formatted table but current work around is ok.

Comment: Perhaps the same as  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43383591/how-to-see-all-rows-of-a-data-frame-in-a-jupyter-notebook-with-an-r-kernel#43597230 ? The answer there is `options(repr.matrix.max.rows=600, repr.matrix.max.cols=200)`