# How to see all rows of a data frame in a Jupyter notebook with an R kernel?

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-irkernel

When I put a data frame into a cell, it shows only some of the rows, with a "..." in the middle.

**Edit**: I'm looking for R equivalents of these Python notebook calls:

```
import pandas
# "If max_cols is exceeded, switch to truncate view"
pandas.set_option('display.max_columns', 5400)
# "The maximum width in characters of a column"
pandas.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 500)
```

See also http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.set_option.html.

Comment: Try printing the output? E.g. `library(plyr); m1 <- ldply(iris, rep, 3); print(m1)`

Comment: Thanks! The "print" function removes the nice HTML table formatting (lining up the values, nicer-looking fonts, table lines, ..).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Thomas Kluyver [says](https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel/issues/470):

> I think the options you want are repr.matrix.max.rows and
>   repr.matrix.max.cols
>
> i.e. run
>
> ```
> options(repr.matrix.max.rows=600, repr.matrix.max.cols=200)
> ```
>
> The defaults are 60 and 20.